# Print character which is in an array

Tags: c, arrays, printf, strtok

```
char input[100];
char *word;
gets(input);
word=strtok(input, " ");
char str[15];
str[0]=word;
printf("%c", str[0]);
```

This is my code except headers. I tried to print out the character but it didn't work. How could I fix it...? I expected to see the character that I got from strtok().

Comment: You wanted to print the word or the first character from the word? `strtok` doesn't return  `char`

Comment: Do you not get any warning for your code? Also, don't use `gets()` ever.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. Please clarify.

Comment: I wanted to get the first word from my input.

Comment: never use `gets()`.  It has been depreciated  for years and is completely removed from the latest C standard.  Suggest using `fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin );`

Comment: regarding: `word=strtok(input, " ");`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned pointer to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `str[0]=word;`  This will copy the address value, found in `word` into a single character in the array `str[]`  This will not work for several reasons, including an address is several bytes.  Perhaps you meant: `strcpy( str, word );`  and even that is `ifffy` because there is no guarantee that the string pointed to be `word` is only 14 characters (plus the NUL terminator byte)

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c", str[0]);`  this statement will only place the first character in the array `str[]` into the `stdout` stream buffer.  When the program exits the character will be printed.  However, that is a poor method of getting the output displayed on the terminal.  Suggest: `printf("%c\n", str[0]);` as the 'newline' will force the `stdout` buffer to be printed immediately.  Note: this only prints the first character.  To print the word in `str[]` use: `printf( "%s\n", str );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all don't use `gets()`.

Then you did this `str[0]=word;` which is wrong. Two way to get away with it. Either use array of pointers and duplicate the string or copy the word in `str`.

```
char input[100];
char *word;
char str[15];
if(fgets(input,100,stdin)){
   word=strtok(input, " ");
   if( word && strlen(word)<15){
      strcpy(str,word);
      printf("First word: %s\n", str);   
   }
}
```

Or else

```
char input[100];
char *word;
char* str[5];
if(fgets(input,100,stdin)){
   word=strtok(input, " ");
   if( word ){
      str[0]=strdup(word);
      printf("First word %s\n", str[0]);   
   }
}
```

Or even more simply if you know that there is space between those words as you said

```
char input[100];
char str[15];
if(fgets(input,100,stdin)){
   if( sscanf(input,"%14s",str) == 1){
     printf("First word %s\n",str);
   }   
}
```

---

To store all the words you need to extend the code a bit - I will show you the one with `strdup` the other can be similarly done.

```
char input[100];
char *word;
char* str[5];
size_t cnt = 0;
if(fgets(input,100,stdin)){
   word=strtok(input, " ");
   while( word != NULL ){
      str[cnt]=strdup(word);
      printf("%zu word %s\n",cnt, str[cnt]);
      cnt++;
      word=strtok(NULL, " ");             
   }
}
```

Free the duplicated strings after you are done working with it.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` returns pointer to `char`. You need to dereference `word` before assigning it to `str[0]` as `str[0]` is of type `char`.
Change

```
str[0]=word;
```

to

```
str[0] = *word;
```

Answer (score 0):

[strtok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) returns the pointer which refers to next token (in this case first token), so if you want to access the first character of this token, you must use `word[0]`. In your code, line `str[0]=word` is automatically casted to `str[0]=(char)word`, which means
first byte of address of pointer.

```
char input[100];
char *word;
gets(input);
word=strtok(input, " ");
char str[15];
str[0]=word[0];
printf("%c", str[0]);
```